# ImageMagick convert SVG using my true type font (Magick++)

Tags: c++, c, svg, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am using `Magick++` API of `ImageMagick`. I cannot find out how to set up rendering svg to raster with my font. [this is my svg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/974n4uzu2krqqrt/ua_03.svg) .

The goal is to achieve analog of

```
convert.exe -font C:\Fonts\RoadSymbols.ttf C:\ua_03.svg C:\1.png
```

but using `Magick++` API.

I tried to set up font like this:

```
Magick::Image svgImage("C:\\ua_03.svg");
svgImage.magick("png");
svgImage.font("@C:\\Fonts\\RoadSymbols.ttf");
svgImage.write("C:\\1.png");
```

But I had't got required result.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why is there an `@` sign in the path to the font?

Comment: here http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image.html said at the function void font(string ) that If the font is a fully qualified X server font name, the font is obtained from an X  server. To use a TrueType font, precede the TrueType filename with an @. Otherwise, specify  a  Postscript font name (e.g. "helvetica").

Comment: but I had also tried without it

Comment: And the lack of double slashes?

Comment: sorry, it's typo. It doesn't work with double slashes

Answer (score 1):

First use a commandline to list all fonts which are known to ImageMagick:

```
 convert.exe -list font
```

You'll see something like this:

```
Path: /opt/local/etc/ImageMagick/type-ghostscript.xml
Font: AvantGarde-Book
  family: AvantGarde
  style: Normal
  stretch: Normal
  weight: 400
  glyphs: /opt/local/share/fonts/urw-fonts/a010013l.pfb
Font: AvantGarde-BookOblique
  family: AvantGarde
  style: Oblique
  stretch: Normal
  weight: 400
  glyphs: /opt/local/share/fonts/urw-fonts/a010033l.pfb
Font: AvantGarde-Demi
  family: AvantGarde
  style: Normal
  stretch: Normal
  weight: 600
  glyphs: /opt/local/share/fonts/urw-fonts/a010015l.pfb
Font: AvantGarde-DemiOblique
  family: AvantGarde
  style: Oblique
  stretch: Normal
  weight: 600
  glyphs: /opt/local/share/fonts/urw-fonts/a010035l.pfb
[...]
```

Then, when it comes to picking a font for ImageMagick's peruse from that list, you can choose:

- (a) ...either use the font name that appears behind the `Font:` tag,
- (b) ...or use the full path to the actual font file (which appears behind the `glyphs:` tag.

And do not try to use just the `family:` name with ImageMagick...

**Be sure to use quotes around any the fontname or the path should they contain any blanks!**

Comment: Ok,thank you for answer. But how to specify font file path in code? Why it's doesn't work?
I am interesting because 
convert.exe -font C:\Fonts\RoadSymbols.ttf C:\ua_03.svg C:\1.png
works fine

Comment: You should [check this](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/STL.html#coderInfoList) and test if your Magick++ even supports SVG processing...

Comment: ofcourse supports. It converts svg but with default font. Since convert.exe utility supports specifying of true type fonts hence I can suggest that ImageMagick Magick++ or Wand or Core supports it also

Comment: @dmigous: I'm not sure if each one of Magick++/Wand/Core do indeed wrap the *complete* IM functionality into their APIs.... IM sometimes uses *external* 'delegates' for some processing steps -- these may not be readily available for the APIs.